# Best way to select column with OR condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am comparing data where the same quantities are given by different names ('radius', 'r', 'Radius[m]', etc.) in the different DataFrames I am comparing. Now I need to loop over these DataFrame and select a quantity. What would be the most elegant/clean way to select column based on an `OR` condition? So ideally I would do

```
df['r' or 'radius']
```

However this obviously would not work. What would be the closest to this that would work?

Comment: Try this `df[['r', 'radius']]`.

Comment: That gives me a KeyError. Maybe I am not describing it clear enough. so df1 has column 'r ' and not 'radius' and df2 has column 'radius' and not 'r'. I want to select either of the two depending on which one exist in the DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

Assuming each dataframe will only contain one of those quantities, you can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) all the possible quantities to `r`, so then you can always access as `df['r']`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'radius': 'r', 'Radius[m]': 'r'})
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Radius[m]': [42,13,100], 'foo': [0,1,2]})
df = df.rename(columns={'radius': 'r', 'Radius[m]': 'r'})
df['r']

# 0    42
# 1    38
# 2   100
# Name: r, dtype: int64
```

---

#### [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html)

If there are potentially multiple quantities in a dataframe, use [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) to find the overlapping names:

```
quantities = ['r', 'radius', 'Radius[m]']
columns = df.columns.intersection(pd.Index(quantities))
```

Examples:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'r': [1,2,3], 'foo': [20,40,60]})
columns = df1.columns.intersection(pd.Index(quantities))
df1[columns]

#    r
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'radius': [100,200,300], 'foo': [0,1,2]})
columns = df2.columns.intersection(pd.Index(quantities))
df2[columns]

#    radius
# 0     100
# 1     200
# 2     300
```

Comment: Nice, very elegant. It may be worth stating that you're accepting the unstated assumption in the question that any of the input dataframes will only contain one of the items in `quantities`.

Comment: @butterflyknife good idea, will note it

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about intersection so I will go with that one